# Android multi-purpose listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Been really confused for a some time now, i've been working on my app i have no code on what i've tried because i dont know where to start. Ok, What type of view does instagram/facebook use to play both images and videos on the same listview do they make multiple view depending on the content they recieve or do they just use textureview or surfaceview to display both images and videos, Please Help.

Comment: They probably use different view types. See [`Adapter.getItemViewType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inflate different layouts according to the row type.

Override `getItemViewType(int position)` and return the correct type for the given position.
Then you use returned type to inflate the correct layout.

The operation is a little bit complex, and you should read this [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Although, since you're learning to use the ListView, I would recommend you to learn also the RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is faster and probably better. Take a look [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465)